# Python: simple parallel example not working

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to learn about multiprocessing in Python and I was having a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso).
According to it, the following code should run in about 1 second:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def do_something():
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print('Done sleeping!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print('Time', finish-start)
```

but when I run it, I get an execution time of more than 2 seconds.

```
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Done sleeping!
Done sleeping!
Time 2.1449603
```

Why is that happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce... on my system it prints `Time 1.0089325113222003`

Comment: exactly, it should run that way... I don't really know why it is doing that...

Comment: For linux it is possible to run `strace -fttT <script_name>` and check, what takes time

Comment: `What am I missing?` a few cores maybe ?